# Knockout.js - When using templates, how do I know to which dom element a given model is bound?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a page where I'm repeating large sections using a foreach:

```
<div class="module-wrapper" 
  data-bind="template: { name: 'dependent-template', foreach: dependentInformation }">    
</div>
```

I'm setting up the logic in these sections and need to run some jquery (addClass()) when a model value changes.  But I can't figure out how to get a handle on the current model's bound DOM element.

Anyone know this?

## Update

When reading about afterRender, I saw afterAdd, which I'm now using:

```
<div class="module-wrapper" 
       data-bind="template: { 
         name: 'dependent-template', 
         foreach: dependentInformation, 
         afterAdd: setClassFromModelState }">
</div>
```

This wasn't as clean as I would have liked because, although I only have two items in my dependentInformation array, the afterAdd() is called 4 times for each item (text, the DOM object, comment, and another text).

So, I have to then inspect the element to know when to actually do what I want:

```
self.setClassFromModelState = function(element, index, data){
    if ($(element).hasClass("cat") && $(element).hasClass("form-group")) {
        $(element)
            .removeClass("off")
            .removeClass("summary")
            .removeClass("edit")
            .addClass(data.model_state());
    }
};
```

Would rather have a cleaner way to do this... but this is working...

## Another Update

Just read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/Z4SmI7IGjWA) that I should check the node type to do what I want:

```
self.setClassFromModelState = function(element, index, data){
   if (element.nodeType === 1) {
        $(element)
           .removeClass("off")
           .removeClass("summary")
           .removeClass("edit")
           .addClass(data.model_state());
   }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/awCRM/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [afterRender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) event of the foreach binding will give you access to the generated dom.

> afterRender — is invoked each time the foreach block is duplicated and
>   inserted into the document, both when foreach first initializes, and
>   when new entries are added to the associated array later. Knockout
>   will supply the following parameters to your callback:
>
> - An array of the inserted DOM elements
> - The data item against which they are being bound

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the MVVM pattern, ViewModel's aren't supposed to technically interact with the View directly thus Knockout doesn't really give you a good clean way of accessing the DOM element to which any particular property is bound. (see Knockout's description of MVVM [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm_and_view_models).)

My suggestion would be to use the [`css`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding provided by knockout to toggle classes, or if that doesn't work for you, you may need to implement a custom [binding handler](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/goqLWqIxxZA/5Ee3AwIQoW0J) to handle the interplay.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep your MVVM clean and play with the DOM (=the view) directly, is to use the [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) ability of knockout.js

Comment: I like the idea of this, but to do this means I'd have to re-implement the template binding function to accept my new property...